# Correct way of applying REST in Rails 3 many User Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I want to apply REST to my Rails 3 application.

I understand the basics but am still a NOOB and would like some help or advice if this is correct.

I have a USER model.  However I have three kinds of User, as in they have different roles in the application.

When I create say the Celebrant I need to do other things in the create action that are different then the things I need to to for the Manager which is again different from what I need to do for the Participant.

So I was thinking of creating three resources.

```
1.Celebrant - new create only
2.Manager -new create only
3.Participant. -new create only
```

This way I can have the three REST NEW and CREATE actions that are different from each.

Is this the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts…

### 1. DRY

If `Celebrant`, `Manager`, and `Participant` all extend `User`, then it's best to have 1 controller.  Most of the code will be the same between the 3 controllers otherwise.

### 2. [Fat Models, Skinny Controllers](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model)

The controllers just pass parameters to models, so really you should only have to call 1 method on the model in the controller, like `User.create`.  This makes it so your controllers don't perform any logic, so you don't need 3 separate controllers.

Check out the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem to pretty much remove all code from your controllers.

Doing it like this, you handle what happens before/after create in each of your `User` model subclasses.

### 3. Using a Role model instead of User subclasses

I ran into your exact problem before.  I started with 3 user classes.  But I quickly wanted to do more with the roles, add more, blur the lines, etc.  By having 1 `User` model which `has_many :roles` (there's role plugins out there), you can handle all your custom logic in your save callbacks in the user model based on roles.  Now your controller is lean, and you don't have to manage 3 classes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Viatropos.  I appreciate what you say.  I think in my case I don't put the role in the user model. Its in a Participants model. I just want to use REST for three controllers as the code is significantly different when I create each Participant. I guess its best not to go into it here for this question. I use the same create function for the User. I just can't use the same Controller action. I will look into your suggestion for the callbacks though.